# Source control and branches for a project using gulp

Tags: jquery, node.js, git, github, gulp

*I am new to node.js/gulp and therefore apologies about the simple question.*

I am creating a new jQuery project. And I am using *node.js* and *gulp* in my environment. Here is the directory/file structure.

```
/root-pluign-directory
    |
    ---- dist (directory that contains the files for release)
    |
    ---- src (directory containing the source code)
    |
    ---- node_modules (node.js modules used in my project)
    |
    ---- gulpefile.js (gulp file/instructions to manage my code from "src" to "dist", including minify, uglify, ... etc.)
    |
    ---- package.json (the package file for my project)
```

Now, when I use source control, what is the recommended way to check in and manage my code? Should I do the following?

- Create a branch called **gulp** that contains *node_modules*, *gulpfile.js*, and *package.json*,
- And create another branch, **dist**, for the *dist* directory,
- And create more branches, such as **master** and **any-additional-development-branch** for the *src* directory

Is this the way to do it? What is recommended? What is the right approach.

Previously, I created a **vendors** branch, for all third party libraries in my project, but *gulp* is for development purposes, not for distribution purposes, so **vendors** would not work in this case.

Thanks.

### Update

I previously created projects in PHP, mostly custom WordPress development, and now I am using node.js and gulp for the first time. My confusion is the following: the *node_modules* directory, the *gulpefile.js* and the *package.json* files, and the *dist* directory. I am not sure what to with them, Should add *node_modules* to .gitignore? What about the *gulpefile.js* and *package.json* files, and the *dist* directory?.

Thanks again.

Comment: do you have previous experience in managing projects in GIT ??

Comment: @RJ- Um, yes. But on different file structures. I normally do not include *dist*, nor *node_modules*. This is a new environment setup, and hence my confusion. How do you suggest I proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source control manager is here to track your changes, therefor your files.

While gulpfile.js and package.json are two files you'll certainly change thus need to be tracked, i'd recommend you not to track the node_modules as you won't change anything yourself here ( npm will ).

Second, git branches are here to track and isolate the different feature you might be working on at the same time.

I'd suggest you read [the excellent guide on git-scm about branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) and when you'll need to get a better branching model, might I suggest [this link](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) giving really good advice on how to use branches efficiently.

Comment: Thanks Vincent.  I actually do follow the branching model described in the link you provided. My concern is the following: the *node_modules* directory, the *gulpefile.js* and the *package.json* files, and the *dist* directory. I am not sure what to with them, Based on your suggestion, then I should add *node_modules* in .gitignore, right? What about the rest?

Comment: except src, package.json and gulpfile add everything to .gitignore.  The real reson is explained in the above links.

Comment: Depends on what you do with those folders.
If you modify dist as well ( copy-past some libraries for exemple ), you might want to track this folder.

Comment: By the way, you should never have to do a branch based only on a folder. It does not make sense. I really can't see a reason to create a dist branch only to track the dist folder

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I also spent the last hour or so reading about that issue. Now I have a 95% understanding on how npm works. I think the remaining 5% will come from actually experiencing it.